# GXT3 How to get row of edited cell

Tags: grid, gxt

What I am trying to do, after editing a cell in in a GridInlineEditing grid, is get the model (or record, don't care which) of the row that was just edited.

I tried attaching a ValueChangeHandler to the editor, but the ValueChangeEvent has no context and the source seems to be the same regardless of which row I edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<> selectedItems =  editorGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
       //iterate selected items
      int index = editorGrid.getStore().indexOf(selectedItem);
```